# How to present (key) publications on personal website?

Tags: publications, citations, website

I am a phd student in a STEM field and currently setting up a personal website. The website is intended to be simple and will basically contain contact details, research interests, a list of publications and links to other profiles in the web (I have a very common name).

Beside the pure list of publications I think it would be a good idea to highlight "key" publications in some way, so that visitors can detect at a glance what I consider my most relevant research. However, I am not sure how to approach this at best.

The only idea I have so far is to provide one picture (maybe animated) for each "key" presentation that gives an overview of the corresponding paper, like e.g. in http://innovate.ee.ucla.edu/refereed-journal-publications.html

Any more/better ideas? Examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common solution which I usually see is having a section called "Selected Publications" or "Key Publications". Often people show the details only for these and you have to take some extra step (e.g. press some link or an "expand button") in order to get the full publication list.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @snaix for example: https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/josiemer-mattei/publications/